# Expand tableviewcell when selected and compact when deselected Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I have a mainTableView of type ExpyTableView (https://github.com/okhanokbay/ExpyTableView). All fine , i managed to implement it and make it work but as it can be seen in the gif below i need to make +1 extra action for DidSelect and DidDeselect.

[image: demo gif]

The thing is i want when selected to highlight with the green color and immediately expand the other rows , and when clicked on it right after to deselect and make the row back to normal . So normally this need to happen only after 2 taps on the screen... instead i make 4  as seen in the gif.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //MARK : Print
    print("Selected Section \(indexPath.section), Row : \(indexPath.row)")
    ///////////////
   
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        if (indexPath.section == 1) || (indexPath.section == 2) || (indexPath.section == 3) {
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        cell.layer.borderColor = Theme.defaultColor().cgColor
        cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: 0.5, height: 0.5)
        }
    }
}

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.1
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        
    }
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Hi, and what's the issue ? Please update the description with exact problem and expected result. 

I guess it is, that the cell remains highlighted (not highlighting the whole content) and unhighlights only after deselecting, right ? 

So expected result would be: 
1. Highlight
2. Make the whole cell including the expansion highlighted ? 
3. Unhighlight on deselection (collapse) 
Am I right ? If not please update the description.

Comment: As i said when tapped on the row to highlight and expand  ..as for deselecting click again on the row contract and get the default layer.border. This should be made with only 2 taps. Instead in my current project this is made in 4 steps as seen in the gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you listen to table changes for `didDeselectRow` which means following: 
The code is executed once the table view cell is deselected. So you can forget about that code unless you really need it. However what you did is that you **`selects`** the row twice. Once for expansion, secondly to collapse.

What you need to do is to remember the index of selected cell and then deselect it while id **`didSelectRowAt`**
So declare a property `fileprivate var currentlySelectedCellIndexPath: IndexPath?` and then in `didSelectRowAt` use following.

```
var currentlySelectedCellIndexPath: IndexPath?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let currentlySelectedCellIndexPath = currentlySelectedCellIndexPath {
        // unselect the selected one
        makeCellUnSelected(in: tableView, on: currentlySelectedCellIndexPath)
        guard currentlySelectedCellIndexPath != indexPath  else {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: currentlySelectedCellIndexPath , animated: true)
            self.currentlySelectedCellIndexPath = nil
            return
        }
    }

    // Highlight the proper cell
    makeCellSelected(in: tableView, on: indexPath)
    currentlySelectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
}

func makeCellSelected(in tableView: UITableView, on indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        if (indexPath.section == 1) || (indexPath.section == 2) || (indexPath.section == 3) {
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
            cell.layer.borderColor = Theme.defaultColor().cgColor
            cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: 0.5, height: 0.5)
        }
    }
}

func makeCellUnSelected(in tableView: UITableView, on indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.1
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    }
}
```

To explain what it does: 
The functions makeCellselected & makeCellUnselected just apply the style changes to highlight / unhighlight the cell as you did previously.

in the function `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` just check for currently visible and selected cell. If it is the same cell, then collapse it in guard and return, since you require only to expand / collapse. If it is not the same cell, then just discard the selection by calling `makeCellUnselected` and select the new one. This should solve your problem so far. If you have any other questions, just let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the respons. There are 2 errors:  @1 - let currentlySelectedCellIndexPath changed to var . and @2 - it is saying currentlySelectedCellIndexPath = nil   => Nil cannot be assigned to type 'IndexPath'

Comment: @FagadariuMarcel Oh yeah, got you, I forgot `self` in if let section. Corrected.

Comment: indeed it works very well but I needed to comment self.mainTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true in order to work only with 1 TouchUpInside. The thing is if I want i can select all 3 rows , now i'm limited at just 1. Any ideea? Even so , thanks dude.

Comment: That's a different problem to solve. In this case it would be better to have the contents of the cell wrapped in any kind of `Model` and keep the expanded / collapsed information inside the model. So in `didSelectRowAt` you would change the particular model information and expand / collapse it's cell appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to have a property in your model `isExpanded` that will store if the cell needs to be expanded. That way you can use it in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` where you will get the item and read the `isExpanded` property.